# Can not find firebase-core when created project with google maps activity

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to connect my google maps activity to Firebase. I've done it too many times in projects created as blank activity but it can not find firebase-core-15.0.1 in the project created as google maps activity. I dont know if it is related with maps. I've tried too many answers in the net but not fixed yet :( 
Tried too much thing. What to do to fix?

Ps: google repo, play services, sdk tools are up to date.

**here's gradle build error:**

```
Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  file:/Users/gks/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.pom
  file:/Users/gks/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.jar
  file:/Users/gks/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.pom
  file:/Users/gks/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.jar
  file:/Users/gks/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.pom
  file:/Users/gks/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.jar
  file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.pom
  file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.jar
  https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.pom
  https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.jar
  https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.pom
  https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.jar
Required by: 
     project :app
```

**here's build gradle:app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "in.gks.app"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
 }

 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}


 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build grade:project**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

 buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
}

  allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
  }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**edit:** tried to add

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.1"
```

too but can not find in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'd need to add these `dependencies` to the module-level `build.gradle` -

in this case, version `16.0.1` does work together with `play-services:15.0.1`:

```
dependencies {
    api "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
    api "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1"
}
```

and maybe update the build-script `dependencies`, as well:

```
 buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. i tried all you suggested but i am facing with that error: ***Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.*** tried to change api of firebase version to 27.1.1 but can not find with that.

Comment: okay, thanks anyway. just added ***compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'*** to fix.

Answer (score 0):

It's self-explanatory, I believe: you forgot to add inside your `gradle:app`:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.1"
```

Since version 15 it's mandatory to add this dependency, previously you didn't have to add it as a standalone one, it was included inside firebase

Comment: thanks for answer. i've tried, can not find in that way too.